# Unsure about calculation step

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I have the following calculation step while computing a norm and I am not sure whether it is correct... and I find no way to show it.

$n \cdot \int_0^\infty \exp(-p(nx))\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^\infty \exp(-px)\mathrm{d}x $

Can someone help me please?

Comment: $$x \mapsto \frac{x}{n}$$

Comment: thx my friend ;)